# Android SHA1 is painfully slow

Tags: java, android, performance, java-native-interface, sha

Am I doing it wrong, or Android's JVM implementation of SHA1 is painfully slow? My code is below:

```
in = new FileInputStream("/mnt/sdcard/200mb");
MessageDigest digester = MessageDigest.getInstance("sha1");
byte[] bytes = new byte[8192];
int byteCount;
int total = 0;
while ((byteCount = in.read(bytes)) > 0) {
    total += byteCount;
    digester.update(bytes, 0, byteCount);
    Log.d("sha", "processed " + total);
}
```

and here is log:

```
10-31 13:59:53.790 D/sha     ( 3386): processed 4931584
10-31 13:59:54.790 D/sha     ( 3386): processed 5054464
10-31 13:59:55.780 D/sha     ( 3386): processed 5177344
```

which is about 100k / sec, for me it is unacceptable.

I am using physical device (LG P990, 2.2.2). Can I get better results with Java, or I have to look into JNI implementation?

I have played with buffer size - no significant difference.

## Traceview results

So it seems the bottleneck is in updating hash.

[image]

## Research

That is interesting. When I have tried on 2.3.2 (SE Xperia), processing speed was about 12meg/sec. When I've tried on 2.2 (HTC Legend), the speed was even slower than at first device. Could it be so that something has been changed since 2.3?

Comment: move the logging out of the loop and test again

Comment: Implemented logging in a way that it prints message when megabytes has changed - same results (120kb/sec)

Comment: Benchmark what is read time and what is hash time, you may spend much more time reading that you think you are. Also try to play with different buffer sizes, increasing it could help a lot, 8k chunks are likely smaller than a file system block on your card.

Comment: Added traceview results. I have played with buffer size - no significant difference.

Comment: On iOS I am able to get close to 10m hashes per second, and that's in SHA256 environment.... using a Samsung Galaxy S5 I am seeing around 150k hash per second. Honestly an embarrassing difference in performance between iOS and Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to my benchmarks, that code should easily be able to perform way better than 120 kb/s (I'm running on different hardware, but still).

If you profile the code with [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html), where is the time spent? If the bottleneck is FileInputStream.read(), think about:

- if some other app is using the sdcard at the same time as you, like a media indexing app or something. Sharing bandwidth with some other app will have an adverse effect on the sdcard reading performance of your app.
- If the sdcard itself is the problem. Try another sdcard or re-format the one you have.

If the bottleneck is MessageDigest.update() (which I doubt), I guess you do need to look into a JNI solution. For your information, the SHA-1 implementation already is in native code (see [android_message_digest_sha1.cpp](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/21e6e2de1f0062f949fcc52d0b4559dfa3246e0e/core/jni/android_message_digest_sha1.cpp)), but maybe you can gain a speedup by avoiding some native <-> Java copying.

**Update 1 (Please ignore):**

(Based on your profiling, the problem seems to be that you don't use Android's optimized `android.security.MessageDigest` but instead `java.security.MessageDigest`. Try `android.security.MessageDigest` instead. Both Android 2.2 and 2.3 have native SHA-1 implementations of `android.security.MessageDigest`.)

**Update 2:**

Sorry, I forgot about `android.security.MessageDigest` being internal. I now realize that I was also using `java.security.MessageDigest` in my benchmarking. I was running on Android 2.3 though, and it turns out the SHA-1 implementation of `java.security.MessageDigest` in Android 2.3 is in native code as well, while that appearently is not the case on Android 2.2.

So the answer to your original question is: Yes, it is painfully slow in Android 2.2 due to a Java implementation but significantly faster in Android 2.3 due to an implementation in native code. You should see similar speedups on Android 2.2 if you use your own SHA-1 implementation in native code.

Comment: I have added trace results. It seems bottleneck is in update().

Comment: How can I use android.security package? It does not seem to be part of public API.